# setNeedsDisplay in a UIView subclass (in an ipad Splitview) not calling drawRect

Tags: ios, ipad

My Question is about the setNeedsDisplay method which is in my UIView sub class which doesn't call the drawRect in the same class.

I'm developing an Ipad application to show a X Y Graph (cartesian plane) where a user can enter coordinates for points. (ex: 2,4 and 2,8: this should draw a straight vertical line).
I used a Master-Detail Application (so a split view controller).

1) Initially the drawRect in the UIView subclass draw the initial grid. I need to add the lines on the fly to the grid, when user adding the new points (x, y values)

2) And then after entering the x and y values (in the MasterViewController), I'm calling the point update method in UIView subclass (gridview) like the following:

```
- (void) updateGrid
{
    // this is a mutable array of newly created points
    self.gridview.pointList = self.pointList; 
    [self.gridview redrawGrid];
}
```

3) I have the setNeedsDisplay in the method, "redrawGrid" in the UIView subclass (gridview) to call the drawRect in order to redraw the grid with new data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have a problem inside the `drawRect:`. Put a breakpoint inside the `drawRect:` method and you should see very fast what's going on.

Also make sure that `setNeedsDisplay` is really called.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But yes I tried to putting break points into the drawRect method, but no luck.

this is my redrawGrid method in the UIView subclass (gridview.m):
- (void) redrawGrid {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

Comment: @ChristinaWatson oh, I see you did accept the answer. What was the problem then?

Comment: the problem is "setNeedsDisplay" doesn't seems to be calling the drawRect function. Not sure My approach is a better one to update/refresh the Grid (which is in the Detail view of the split view)

Comment: @ChristinaWatson There is no problem with the detail controller. Maybe `self.gridView` in your controller is `nil` and you don't even call `redrawGrid`?

Comment: hmm, I don't think so as the call (self.gridView) goes inside to the redrawGrid method (in the UIVIew subclass), but the setNeedsDisplay inside the method doesn't trigger a drawRect call. :(

Comment: @ChristinaWatson What you are saying is impossible (if you are not tampering with the view layer). You should post the code.

Comment: can you email your email address to my email address: christina.wat45@yahoo.com So that I will email back you the full code project. Thank you very much.

Comment: ok so following is my UIView Subclass:
- (void) redrawGrid {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
-(void) drawGrid {
    // grid drawing code here. and it works fine
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [self drawGrid];
    for (int i = 1; i <= sizeof(self.pointList); i++) {
        // line drawing code here. (getting the points from the mutable array)
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(path);
}
@end

// Thank you